# Magento 1.9.3: Need extra fee specific plugin

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group, extrafee

I have a specific need:

I need a plugin (no problem if paid) that allows me to apply an extra fee on specific products and per customer group.

The situation in detail is this:

- General customers will purchase specific products with an extra tax included in the price (in this case no intervention, I will add the tax to the price of the product)
- Wholesale customers will purchase specific products with an extra tax separately, to be displayed in the cart (+ VAT), and to be totalized in the order.
- Wholesale customers of a specific customer group will purchase specific products with an extra fee, but without paying it.

The features I'm looking for are:

- possibility to specify different taxes (fixed and obligatory) by product / category, I will have different products taxed, with a tax per product, but different taxes according to the characteristics of the product
- possibility to assign the fee to different store views
- possibility of excluding the tax to certain customer groups
- display of the tax on the product page, on the cart, on the invoice and on the order summary

The best plugin that ive find is this (that seems to do everything
, except the customer group choice):
https://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-extra-fee-extension

Any suggestions?

Comment: try this https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee